# Unable to access SharePoint from VBA or PowerShell to change the list view "Hidden" flag

Tags: vba, powershell, sharepoint

At work, I am using SharePoint.

I need to change the hidden status of some list views to remove some of the clutter.

"Easy" I thought - but oh dear, how wrong I was!

I looked in the list views and can only see that I can delete the view, which we don't want to do.

So, I thought I would look into using PowerShell to effect the changes.

I was able install a SharePoint module, and can see commands relating to SP are available, but still cannot access a SP site.

If I use a "normal" PowerShell, when I try to authenticate using Connect-SPOService -url https://.sharepoint.com, I get the error "Connect-SPOService: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"

If I try using the SharePoint PowerShell, it says I am not authorised - which could be true as I am merely a worker!

So, I thought I would try to use VBA, which I thought would confer benefits, as I could compare the current sites, and then update the ones I want - which would help in case we want to re-enable the visibility of sites.

I couldn't find worked examples in MS, and I checked that I had all the SP references enabled, yet I cannot get e.g.

```
site = new SPSite("https://<company>.sharepoint.com")
```

to work - VBA has a compile error "Syntax Error", so I am completely stuck.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Many thanks,

As detailed above, I started with looking in the List Views I wanted to hide, without finding the answer. Then I tried PowerShell, and SharePoint PowerShell, trying to follow any guidance/ ... and then swapped to VBA, and it feels like I have tried every option, from SOAP, ADO to "just" accessing the site using SPSite.

I do wonder if the references in VBA aren't valid (despite enabling them).

I also investigated using Python, but that seemed more limited!

We are using "SharePoint in Microsoft 365", and VBA 7.1.

All of this is on Windows 10.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Many thanks!

Comment: You do not have a authentication error.  Authentication is used to complete a connection and the connection is completing. : I try to authenticate using Connect-SPOService -url https://.sharepoint.com, I get the error "Connect-SPOService: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request".  Bad request means the server is not accepting the request due to a http headers or body not being formatted properly.  Every server is different and the request must contain data that meet server requirements.